# relationship between time and speed in a dataframe

Tags: python

I have a data frame that consists of about 12 million rows and I need to describe the relationship between time and speed. Is there a best time of day to connect? Has it changed throughout the years

the data frame looks like this
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyqVB.png)

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX0Eg.png)
I trued doing a plot with regression but visually it doesn't really tell me a lot
my head
[head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrUMn.png)
how would I go about solving this?

Comment: Don't share image code, share it as code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.